# How can I get default modal window for changing password in Lightswitch after click on button

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have **BUTTON** with this code

```
partial void ChangePassword_Execute(){


}
```

and I would like open default modal window for changing password in Lightswitch

> Application type:
>
> - Client>Web
> - Server>IIS

THX

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Forms Authentication, and the standard shell (or a shell that exposes the user control), there's a combo-like box down in the bottom right-hand corner, that allows the user to change their password.

If you're using Windows authentication, you can't change that from LS, you have to do it through Windows.